# What paths should I place in the bash_profile for homebrew?

Tags: python, bash, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to set up homebrew, in order to use Python, and I've had some problem with my PATH, and I have tried different versions. My bash_profile is a bit messy, and I want to edit it back to a clean version, or clean enough to use homebrew. I have previously used anaconda.

It currently has the following text

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
export PATH=‚Äú/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin‚Äù‚Äô
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=‚Äô/usr/local/bin:Äô
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=‚Äú/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin‚Äù‚Äô
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

What should I do to get it back to what it should be?

Comment: I suspect you could simply delete everything after the conda block. The only directory that I don't think is added by the conda block or part of the default value if `/Library/.../3.6/bin`, which I suspect you simply omit.

Comment: However, if I've decided to delete anaconda, could I also delete the Conda block? I'm currently using Python 3.7, should the `library/frameworks ...` bit be 3.7?

Comment: Absolutely.  All it does is prepare your environment for using anaconda. The purpose of the `>>>`/`<<<` markers is to make it easy to identify what was added to you can remove it later.

Comment: So, if I delete the Conda bit, keep the library frameworks bit, is there anything else I need to keep? I feel I need a bit that keeps usr/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete all of it. If you don't do anything to `PATH` at all, you'll start with a value set by `/usr/libexec/path_helper` by `/etc/profile`, which includes everything your old file was setting explicitly.

You can run `/usr/libexec/path_helper` from the command line to see what it adds; it only prints some shell commands to standard output, without actually executing those commands. The default `/etc/profile` *does* execute those commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the comments from your new version above, you will see the line:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
```

I would probably do:

```
diff .bash_profile.pysave .bash_profile
```

to identify what is different and edit appropriately. I don't use `conda` but it also looks like you might want to just delete the lines from:

```
# >>> conda init >>>
```

to

```
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Finally, I would exit from bash after making the above adjustments, restart terminal and then read here for details on howto install Python: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

---

Comment: I've checked the difference, and it doesn't highlight the Conda bit, but it does mean all the list of paths (including the library bit) should be deleted. Is that sensible?